# Interior of a compact 3-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness

I have an orientable 3-manifold $X$, such that
 $$X=\lbrace(x,y,z)\mid x\neq y \neq z \neq x \rbrace\subseteq S^1\times S^1 \times S^1 $$
How to find a compact 3-manifold $M$ such that $X= interior(M)$

any help please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on Rolf Sievers's answer, written to translate his picture into something more familiar to me.  So, if you like my answer, you should also upvote Rolf's answer!

The first thing to note, is that your space $X$ is nothing but the [configuration space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space#Configuration_spaces_in_mathematics) of $3$ points on a circle, $F(S^1, 3)$.  That is, one way to picture your space $X$ is as three points on $S^1$ which are free to move, but not touch each other.  This, for example, allows one to easily see that $X$ is disconnected.  For if we label the three points $x,y,z$, then by suitable rotations, we may assume $x = (0,1)$.  If we head clockwise from $x$, we either encounter $y$ first or $z$ first - these two possiblilities gives rise to the two connected components of $X$.

Now, one has the following result, which I first found in [Fred Cohen's notes](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~sjack/prosem/Cohen_Singapore.final.24.december.2008.pdf).

> Suppose $G$ is a topological group and $F(G,k)$ denotes the configuration space of $k$ points in $G$.  Then there is a natural homeomorphism $F(G,k) \cong G \times F(G\setminus\{e\}, k-1)$

The proof is straight forward:  given $(g_1,..., g_k)\in F(G,k)$, map it to $(g_1, g_1^{-1} g_2, ..., g_1^{-1} g_k)$.  Given a point $(g, g_1,..., g_{k-1})\in F(G\setminus\{e\}), k-1)$, map it to $(g, gg_1, gg_2,..., gg_{k-1})$.  One easily sees these maps are inverses to each other.

As an added bonus, if $G$ is a Lie group, then the map we just wrote down is not just a homeomorphism, but also a diffeomorphism.

Now, we apply that to your example.  $S^1$ is Lie group, so we see that $F(S^1, 3) = S^1 \times F(S^1\setminus \{e\}, 2)$.

But $S^1\setminus \{e\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (and also to $(0,1)$), which, in particular, is a topological group!  So, $F(S^1\setminus\{e\}, 2) \cong \mathbb{R} \times F(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{e\}, 1)$.

Finally, we note that for any space $Y$, $F(Y,1) = Y$.  So putting this all together, these space you care about is $$X = F(S^1, 3)  \cong S^1\times (0,1) \times [(0,1)\coprod (0,1)]$$ which is homeomorphic to two disjoint copies of $S^1\times (0,1)^2$.

As $(0,1)^2$ is homeomorphic to an open disc of radius $1$, each copy of $S^1\times (0,1)^2$ is the interior of $S^1\times D^2$, just as Rolf claimed.

Comment: Thumps up from me! In class, we were working with configuration spaces right now (braid theory) and this is a neat application.

Comment: I'm glad you like it.  I really hope the OP accepts your answer (and others vote it up).  My post is really just yours in different notation.

Comment: The neat thing here is that you can generalize it to $F(\mathbb S^1,k) = (k-1)!\cdot \mathbb S^1 × ℝ^{k-1}$. I spend some time thinking about that using my elementary methods but after the four dimensional case it got to complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help. I would like to know the geometric structure on $X$, for that, I try to find one of the 8 Thurston Geometries call it $Z$ , then I try to find a supgroup $\Gamma \subseteq Isomt(Z)$ so that $X=int(M)=Z\diagup \Gamma$ Is that right? Could you please help me with that? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe your desired manifold with border $M$ are two disjoint, solid, 2-tori.

First, let's have a look at the coordinates: We can parametrize $\mathbb{S}^1$ as $ℝ/ℤ$. Next we choose new coordinates $(a,b,c)$ on the 3-torus $\mathbb{S}^1×\mathbb{S}^1×\mathbb{S}^1$.

$$(a,b,c) = φ(x,y,b) = (x, y-x, z-y)$$
$$(x,y,z) = φ^{-1}(a,b,c) = (a, a+b, a+b+c)$$

We see that $φ$ is a homeomorphism from $ℝ^3$ to $ℝ^3$ and both $φ$ and $φ^{-1}$ map the subset $ℤ^3$ into $ℤ^3$. It follows that this defines an homeomorphism from $T^3 = ℝ^3/ℤ^3$ to itself.

What happens to our equations?

- $x \neq y ⇔ a \neq a + b ⇔ b \neq 0$
- $y \neq z ⇔ a+b \neq a + b+c ⇔ c \neq 0$
- $x \neq z ⇔ a \neq a + b+c ⇔ b+c \neq 0$

$$X \simeq \{(a,b,c)|b\neq0, c\neq0, b+c\neq0\} \subset (\mathbb S^1)^{×3}$$
$$\{(a,b,c)|b+c\neq1\} \subset \mathbb S^1 × (0,1)^2$$
$$\mathbb S^1 × \{(b,c)\in (0,1)^2|b+c\neq1\}$$
Which is a lot easier to handle. It is OK to change the condition to $b+c \neq 1$, as that is the same modulo $ℤ$ and one happens to be the representant of $0$ which is actually in range.

Now $\{(b,c)\in (0,1)^2|b+c\neq1\}$ is just a set of two triangles which almost  touch each other. That almost touching isn't registered by the manifold
structure on $X$. Separating the triangles and taking the closure yields

$$X = \text{interior}(\mathbb S^1 × (\{(b,c) \in [0,1]^2|c \leq b\}\sqcup\{(b,c) \in [0,1]^2|c \geq b\}))$$

Side note: The analogous problem on the $2$-torus gives one strip $\mathbb S^1 × [0,1]$.

Comment: $X$ is connected, but the interiors of two disjoint solid tori are not.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why is $X$ connected? If it is, than I made a mistake somewhere, sure.

Comment: I also tried doing it without a coordinate transformation, but then my diagrams get too messy. So please look for steps in the proof that are unclear or clearly wrong. I'll probably check the coordinate transformation again myself in about 10 Hours. (Gotta go to university now)

Comment: It just hit me this morning $X$ is *not* connected.  I'll have to relook at your answer.  Earlier, I wasn't able to find any kind of mistake, so it's probably fine.

Comment: I just worked through it again.  Looks good to me, and so +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help. I also would like to know the geometric structure on $X$, for that, I try to find one of the 8 Thurston Geometries call it $Z$ , then I try to find a supgroup $\Gamma \subseteq Isomt(Z)$ so that $X=int(M)=Z\diagup \Gamma$ Is that right? Could you please help me with that? many thanks

Comment: Well, those are too many words I never saw. I think you should create a new question for this second part.